# Binding percentage to style from script in Vue 3

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I want to color a cell of a table with two colors such that right and left parts of it has different colors. Yet, I can not dynamically change the portion of the left and right color.

I first tried it by writing style as

```scss
<style lang="scss" scoped>
table {
  th, td {
    $color_right: 50%;
    $color_left: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue $color_right, white $color_left);
  }
}
</style>
```

This works as expected so that the cell is colored as solid blue and solid white.

However, I am having difficulty to change `$color_right` from script.
What I have tried is

```scss
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            color_portion: ref(0.5),
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@function number($string) {
  // Matrices
  $strings: '0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9';
  $numbers: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;

  // Result
  $result: 0;

  // Looping through all characters
  @for $i from 1 through str-length($string) {
    // Do magic
  }

  @return $result;
}

table {
  th, td {
    $color_right: percentage(number(v-bind(color_portion))); // want it to be color_portion%
    $color_left: 50%; // will change to 1 - $color_right
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue $color_right, white $color_left);
  }
}
</style>
```

Unfortunately, `$color_right` seems to be evaluated as just a number as I see the app.
Is there any way to use `v-bind` with percentage?

Comment: Why not just create a computed property where you return the complete percentage as a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Vue `Options API` to define the `data()`, then you don't need to wrap it in `ref/reactive`.

Here is a basic example and working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-cache-dtbwdd?file=/src/App.vue:0-862)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input
      type="range"
      min="1"
      max="100"
      class="slider"
      v-model="color_portion"
      size="2"
    />
    {{ getPercent(color_portion) }}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Body</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      color_portion: 50,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getPercent(num) {
      return parseFloat(num).toFixed(0) + "%";
    },
  }
};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
table {
  th,
  td {
    $color_right: v-bind("getPercent(color_portion)");
    $color_left: v-bind("getPercent(1 - color_portion)");
    background: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      #1FFA01 $color_right,
      white $color_left
    );
  }
}
</style>
```